# CFAttributedString when drawing PDF

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, pdf, nsattributedstring

I'm seriously stuck with this. 
I've used mainly the code from the [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html) and it works fine. Now I am trying to change 1 part and I keep getting errors!!

```
CFAttributedStringRef currentText = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, (CFStringRef)textView.text, NULL);
if (currentText) {
    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(currentText);
    if (framesetter) {
```

I am trying to replace `textView.text` with a single string, so that the PDF is built with the data from the string as opposed to the text view, but when I change that code to

```
CFAttributedStringRef currentText = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, (CFStringRef)stringHere, NULL);
```

it errors me with:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address0x0).
```

I've also tried:

```
CFStringRef stringRef = (CFStringRef)stringHere;
CFAttributedStringRef currentText = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, stringRef, NULL);
```

But i get the same error. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stringHere is 0x0 (aka nil aka NULL)

Comment: Yeah found something i hadn't checked and thats exactly the issue ^